# CSS transform-origin not working with translate()

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

I want to move a div from its center point, but it seems that `translate()` doesn't care what transform-origin is and uses top-left point of the element to move it.

Here is a test to confirm it:

```html
<div class="items" style="">
  <div class="item-1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue; position: absolute; opacity: 0.5; transform-origin: 0% 0%; transform: translate(100px, 100px)"></div>
  <div class="item-2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;  position: absolute; opacity: 0.5; transform-origin: 100% 100%; transform: translate(100px, 100px)"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, bot items are overlapped while it shouldn't.

Question: How to position an element using its center point?

Note: As I'm rotating & moving these items using JS, so just subtracting half of item's width/height is not an option because it needs math that I don't know.

Comment: transform origin has an impact on linear transformation not affine transformation ... all the translation will behave the same whatever the origin which is logical. Translation doesn't need an origin, it's like a vector

Comment: check this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation ... it's all about Math/Geometry and has nothing to do with CSS. So what you need is a different translation not a different origin

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, I'll check it out now.